# Where do I connect my unused C wire to my Goodman Heat Pump?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat-c-wire

I understand similar questions have been asked but I have been unable to extrapolate what has worked for others to my own system. I am trying to upgrade my thermostat to the Ecobee Lite. I have an unused C wire that is not connected to anything at the terminal. Similar to others, the terminal is not straightforward and I do not see an open C spot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Internal Wiring]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not possible (for me at least) to read anything on the diagram you posted.  Please take a better photo of it.

Comment: Yup, even fully zoomed in, it's impossible to read the wiring diagram. Also, specify the exact model number, as Goodman makes a variety...

Comment: Hi guys - Thank you so much for the quick responses! Sorry for the delay. I had to go back on the roof to get some additional photos. The Model # is: GPH1460H41FA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places in the picture where you can attach the C (common) terminal.  I've identified them both in this picture.  I kept the fan palms in because they're great.

[image]

The item in the yellow square is the 24V transformer.  That takes the high voltage (probably 240VAC in your case) and steps it down to the control voltage of 24VAC.  It has two terminals for the high side and two terminals for the low side.  One of the two terminals for the low side is your Common.

Since I can't see the markings on the transformer in the picture, I cannot be sure, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's the terminal with the light blue wires.  Testing with a multimeter between that terminal and the metal frame will give you 0 volts AC.  If it has any other voltage, it is the wrong one.

The item surrounded in pink is the control board.  That may or may not have a terminal labeled 'C', but it will definitely have some terminal that is connected to the Common of the transformer.  You may attach the C wire there as well.  The important thing is the Common terminal has 0 volts to the chassis.  If it has any nonzero voltage reading, that's not the right one.

Inside the machine, wire colors are totally up to the manufacturer and mean pretty much nothing.  If you can reply with the model number of the unit or control board, we would be able to be more sure.

**Update**

Thanks for providing the additional photos.  The photos and the wiring diagram confirm that the light blue wiring is your common on the 24V side.

To attach your thermostat C wire, you can attach directly to the 'C' terminal on your control board (there are two - one is open in the photo).  You could also attach to the transformer, but there are already a lot of cables there.  You'll need to extend your wire and add a female spade terminal, both of which can be found at DIY home center or auto supply stores.  Hook-up wire like you'd find at the auto supply store is perfectly OK to use on the low voltage side.

Note that that white (Is it the same wire as that dust-covered white connected to a C terminal in the close-up - can't really tell) might have been OK once you closed up the box.  Some HVAC equipment has a safety switch that depowers the contactor when you open it up.  The 24V side will then be powered down until you close the case back up.  I don't know if that is how your system works, but it's just a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I updated the post with the additional info you requested. For some additional context, there is a white wire that is unused running from the control board over to the thermostat. I thought it might be attached to a spot labeled "c" on the board but it is honestly hard to tell. I did try connecting the common to it but didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I did exactly what you said and it worked! I really appreciate it!